# Import different shapefiles with a single function into R

Tags: r

I am trying to import different shapefiles into R in a single function:

```
for (i in 1:length(unique)){
   layer = i
    i <- readOGR(dsn="G:/MyDrive/PROCESSING/",
                                 layer = ,
                                 verbose=FALSE,
                                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}
```

However, he manages to insert only the first shape and throws the following error:

First layer 0269 read; multiple layers present in
G:\My Drive\PROCESSING, check layers with ogrListLayers()

Would anyone know how to help me?

Comment: Memo: In this and the following questions, be sure to use a translator. This is an international site in English...

Answer (score 0):

You have at least a couple of problems.

`length(unique)` is unclear. There is a function called `unique()`. Did you create an object in your environment called “unique”? If so, it’s bad practice to name objects after existing functions. If you are trying to use the function, for example, `unique(data)`, the code doesn’t show that. It looks like you created an object called unique and getting the length from it.

Another problem is "i". Your first line is correct, but then the third line assigns a whole function to "i". Why? You can NOT assign multiple objects to it. The "i" (or whatever object you use for the iterator in a for loop) is just to provide an index, not to hold results of processes/functions.

Since part of your post is in Portuguese, I think, I don't know what exactly you're doing. But I'm guessing from the code you are trying to read in a list of files. This will something like what you want.

```
library(rgdal)

# Create an empty list object to hold your function's results
shapefile_list <- list()

# Make a list of the files that are going to be read in from the directory. Get the complete path to the file
listoffiles <- list.files("G:/MyDrive/Processing", pattern="shp", full.names=T)

for(i in 1:length(listoffiles)){
    shapefilelist[i] <- readOGR(listoffiles[i],
    verbose=FALSE,
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}
```

While I'm rewriting this, I will include an option as Jeffery Evans suggested. You can look at his comment after this answer for some more detail.

```
...

# Need the other steps, but skip the for loop and use this instead
shapfilelist <- lapply(listoffiles, readOGR)
```

You might have to tweak this to make it work with your files, but the general form works.

In the future, your post needs to be written completely in English, that's the site's rule, and you need to provide a sample of your data, in this case, a sample of the list of files. And you should include the other code that reproduces your problem. For example, `readOGR` is not a base function in R, you have to import it with `library(rgdal)`.

Comment: You could skip a bunch of code here by simply using something along the lines of `lapply(list.files("G:/MyDrive/Processing", "shp$"), sf::st_read)` which will result in a list object containing the imported shapefiles. BTW, `readOGR' comes from the rgdal package, not sp. These libraries are being depreciated in leu of sf so, answers should represent modern syntax, thus my use of the sf read function.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans yes, you're right about the `lapply`. I only used the for loop because that's what the OP used. Figured I'd stick with what they were somewhat familiar with. And I forgot about the `rgdal`. It's been a while since I've used either of those libraries. I usually want to write answers that reflect the deprecation, but I generally stick to what the OP does.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience, this is my first time using the site.

@JohnPolo   I used your code and got the following error:

Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv, :
   Cannot open layer

I am forwarding a link to a sample database https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UUREl4iW0MNyRGfU6baHW-wpd06JJwGL?usp=share_link

If you can help me.